# Integrating Cassandra with Apache Ignite

Tags: caching, cassandra, ignite

I have downloaded the 2.7.5 binary of Apache Ignite. I referred to the xml file in the Cassandra-Ignite integration official docs. However, all the beans are failing to load. The configuration file is in my desktop folder. Running Ignite from the folder where I have extracted the binary zip.

The error:

```
Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context [springUrl=file:/C:/Users/Username/Desktop/ignite-con-new.xml, err=Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location
```

The config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Cassandra connection settings -->
    <import resource="classpath:org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml" />

    <!-- Persistence settings for 'cache1' -->
    <bean id="cache1_persistence_settings" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.KeyValuePersistenceSettings">
        <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource" value="classpath:org/apache/ignite/tests/persistence/blob/persistence-settings-1.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Persistence settings for 'cache2' -->
    <bean id="cache2_persistence_settings" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.KeyValuePersistenceSettings">
        <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource" value="classpath:org/apache/ignite/tests/persistence/blob/persistence-settings-3.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Ignite configuration -->
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <!-- Configuring persistence for "cache1" cache -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="cache1"/>
                    <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                    <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
                    <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStoreFactory">
                            <property name="dataSourceBean" value="cassandraAdminDataSource"/>
                            <property name="persistenceSettingsBean" value="cache1_persistence_settings"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>

                <!-- Configuring persistence for "cache2" cache -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="cache2"/>
                    <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                    <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
                    <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStoreFactory">
                            <property name="dataSourceBean" value="cassandraAdminDataSource"/>
                            <property name="persistenceSettingsBean" value="cache2_persistence_settings"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                        Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                        instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                        to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                    -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I understand it is failing to find the bean locations. What do you think is a possible fix to this?

The full stacktrace:

```
C:\Users\Username\Downloads\ignitecode\s1>bin\ignite.bat C:\Users\Username\Desktop\ignite-con-new.xml
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context [springUrl=file:/C:/Users/Username/Desktop/ignite-con-new.xml, err=Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml]
Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Users/Username/Desktop/ignite-con-new.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1026)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:351)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:301)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context [springUrl=file:/C:/Users/Username/Desktop/ignite-con-new.xml, err=Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml]
Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Users/Username/Desktop/ignite-con-new.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:392)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:104)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:751)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:952)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:861)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:731)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:700)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:348)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml]
Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Users/Username/Desktop/ignite-con-new.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:233)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:379)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:227)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
        ... 22 more
Failed to start grid: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context [springUrl=file:/C:/Users/Username/Desktop/ignite-con-new.xml, err=Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml]
Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Users/Username/Desktop/ignite-con-new.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist]
```

Comment: Can you show full error message together with stack traces?

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb of reading Spring errors is scrolling all the way down.

```
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
class path resource [org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra/connection-settings.xml] 
cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Looks like the resource is not where your XML expects it to be. Please note that `src/main/resources` can contain arbitrary directory structure, such as `src/main/resources/org/apache/ignite/tests/cassandra` <-- maybe that's where the file should go?